# Can not change Fancybox close button

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, fancybox

I want replace default close button in Fancybox 1.3.4 with custom one. 
I've changed CSS as follows, but button not showing.

```
#fancybox_close {
  width: 66px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('../js/jquery/fancybox/closelabel.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: Could be a path problem with the background in the above css. It all depends on your file structure and where your image is in regards to your css

Comment: the original code has the same path: `background: transparent url('../js/jquery/fancybox/fancybox.png') -40px 0px;` The only difference is that default code have this lines additionally: `z-index: 1103; display: none;`

Comment: if you added display none to the css then thats likely why your not seeing it

Comment: No, I mean original CSS has this display:none, mine code without it.

Comment: can anybody point me why this code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is solved. Just need to be specified correct path to image.